# How can I identify the flaw in the code logic

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and trying to code a simple project but somehow I couldn't get it to work properly.

My code is below:

```
def bones_search(bone_guess, foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]):

    for bones in foot_bones:
        if bones.lower() == bone_guess.lower():
            foot_bones.remove(bone_guess.lower())
            print("Correct!")
            bone_guess = input("Guess 2 - Enter a foot bone: ")
            for bone in foot_bones:
                if bones.lower() == bone_guess.lower():
                    print("Correct!\nNumber of bone guess correct = 2")
                else:
                    pass
            return print("Incorrect!")
        else:
            pass
        print("Incorrect!")
        bone_guess = input("Guess 2 - Enter a foot bone: ")
        for bone in foot_bones:
                if bones.lower() == bone_guess.lower():
                    print("Correct!\nNumber of bone guess correct = 1")
                else:
                    pass
        print("Incorrect!\nNumber of bone guess correct = 0")

bones_search(input("Guess 1 - Enter a foot bone: "))
```

Somehow whenever I entered one of the correct values (e.g. talus) it still prints 'Incorrect!'.

How can I identify the flaw in the logic?

Comment: Instead of `pass`, write the `print` statements inside `else` part.

Answer (score 1):

It's printing Incorrect because, you printed "Incorrect" after your first if-else block.

You are looping through all your foot_bones one by one. So, if your input is not, calcaneus, it will not enter the first if block which is

`if bones.lower() == bone_guess.lower():`

There is no else, so it automatically moved to print `incorrect` and the second for loop starts working. Ultimately your code works, you just have a logical error.

```
Guess 1 - Enter a foot bone: talus
Incorrect!
Guess 2 - Enter a foot bone: talus
Incorrect!
Number of bone guess correct = 0
Correct!
Guess 2 - Enter a foot bone:
```

Maybe instead of asking again for user_input (asking the user to guess again), let the first loop finish.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you need to call the function recursively. As, there are so many bone names, otherwise you will need to write for loops again and again and the program will be very messy to debug! Here is a recursive solution(assuming the player need to guess all the bones):

```
def bones_search(bone_guess, foot_bones):
    global incorrect_guess
    flag = 0
    for bone in foot_bones:
        if bone.lower() == bone_guess.lower():
            foot_bones.remove(bone_guess.lower())
            print("Correct!")
            flag = 1 # means control entered this part
            break
    if flag == 0 and len(foot_bones) > 0:
        print("Incorrect guess :( Try again")
        incorrect_guess += 1
    if len(foot_bones) > 0:
        bones_search(input("Guess other bones: "), foot_bones)
    else:
        print("Well done! You guessed all correctly")

foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid", "navicular", "lateral cuneiform", "intermediate cuneiform", "medial cuneiform"]
incorrect_guess = 0
bones_search(input("Guess a foot bone: "), foot_bones)
print('No. of incorrect guesses:', incorrect_guess)
```

In the above code, every time if the player guesses a correct bone then we remove that bone name and call the function again with the new input and bone name list `foot_bones` after removing the last correctly guessed bone name. If the player's guess is incorrect, then we are saying to guess again. Please don't hesitate to ask for clarification.

**Demo:**
Suppose, we have `foot_bones = ["calcaneus", "talus", "cuboid"]` and user gave the inputs `talus`, `abbb`(wrong input), `calcaneus`, and `cuboid`. The above program will give the output:

```
Guess a foot bone: Correct!
Guess other bones: Incorrect guess :( Try again
Guess other bones: Correct!
Guess other bones: Correct!
Well done! You guessed all correctly
No. of incorrect guesses: 1
```